# Updated: Cycles show missing Texture (magenta)... until i reconnect the materialnodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I have a problem with a textured object in Cycles:

On the Render and Viewport I see a missing texture, but no texture is missing.

It seems not to be a matter of included or external stored textures. In both cases I have the same problem.
The texture shows up correct in the Viewport after reconnecting the Materialnodes in the Node-editor, but after switching to *solid* Viewport Shading and switch back to *rendered* it shows the missing-magenta again.

The material nodes I used are the ones I always use and they worked fine until now. The problem seems to be independent from the used Blender version. Tested the scene in several versions.

How can I fix this?

To explain some uploaded Screenshots:

pseudo-missing texture:
[image: pseudo-missing texture]

after reconnecting nodes:
[image: after reconnecting nodes]

Update:
I use the following Node-setup: 
Texture Coordinate (UV) -> 
Texture Group (DiffuseMap:Color-Data, Glossiness-Map: Non-Color-Data, ReflectionMap: Non-Color-Data, Normal Map: Non-Color-Data) ->
PBR Dialectric Nodegroup (like the one from Blenderguru Tutorial) -> Output

After some more experiments with that problem i found out that the problem seems to be triggered by the Reflection Map. When it's disconneced it works fine. When i connect it then it still works in the viewport and it has the right influence on the used Material. After switching the Viewport Shading to solid and back i have the Pseudo-missing-Texture (Magenta) again.

Update 2:
Tested a bunch of different connections between the nodes... but after quite a lot testing i can find no conclusion where the problem is.

Picture of the Fresnel Node-Setup:
[image: fresnel_node]

Here are some more pictures of the node-setups that i tested:
The ones that seem to work:

[image: works01]

[image: works02]

[image: works03]

[image: works04]

[image: works05]

And the ones that bring me the missing-error:

[image: error01]

[image: error01]

Also tested mixing the Glossy and the Diffuse BDSF with a fix 0.5 value instead of using the Reflection Map... that was resulting in absolute random behavior. Sometimes it worked... sometimes not.

Found a solution! 
Converted the 16-bit png-files into 8-bit png-files. With these the problem doesnt seem to appear. 
But I'm still curious. Perhaps someone has an idea why that happens with the 16bit Textures.

Comment: If that solved your problem, please post that as an answer.

Comment: I can't be sure (so I won't post it as an actual answer), but I suspect that the 16-bit images are big enough that they don't load the same way as 8-bit textures. It seems like the 16-bit textures are "timing out," if such a thing were possible. Almost as if it took too long loading the image, so Blender just assumed it was missing. This might be a bug, and it'd be worth searching the but tracker to see if it's been reported.

Comment: Could not find a reported bug about that. Opened a Bug report...

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution! Converted the 16-bit png-files into 8-bit png-files. With these the problem doesnt seem to appear. But i'm still curious... perhaps someone has an idea why that happens with the 16bit Textures.

I'll have a look at the bugtracker... to see if it's been reported. If not i'll post that in there. (Thanks Matt!)

Comment: This whole thing is quite weird. I went through a dozen of my hundred saved blends (old and new) and always used 16-bit textures. None of them had the missing texture shown. Have you tried to only convert the non-color data textures to 8-bit?

Comment: Tried now... and it seems to work if i convert the non-color data textures to 8-bit. It also works with only a 8-bit normal texture and the rest 16-bit.

Comment: How exactly do you do that?